# How to programmatically program a "Wheel Scroll" using Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, winapi

Is there a way to program a "Scroll wheel" turn on the Windows platform using Ruby?

Kind of similar to programming a click on Windows, or a keyboard key press, but this is to program a scroll wheel turn.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ruby but I can give some hints.

You can do that with the win32 [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

```
// wheel - scroll down
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -WHEEL_DELTA, NULL);
// wheel - scroll up
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, WHEEL_DELTA, NULL);
```

Or you can send the [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to the window.